# programmatically set dynamic resource but FrameWorkElement do not update when ResourceDictionary changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, translation, markup-extensions

Im am using a dynamic resource dictionaries to translate my GUI-elements.
The Dictionaries are loaded on startup or could be changed during runtime.
Works very well!

Now i have to add some GUI-elements programmatically ..
But they will not update after changing the translation..

Here is how i "translate" the GUI-elements in XAML:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:tests.Dialogs" x:Class="tests.Dialogs.Dlg_Main"
    xmlns:Translator="clr-namespace:tests.Translation"
    Title="{DynamicResource DLG_MAIN_TITLE}"
    Height="356" Width="711"
/>
```

This is my MenuItem Class which is added to a ListBox:

```
public class MenuItem : FrameworkElement
{
    public MenuItem (string resourceKey, ClickAction action)
    {
        Action=action;

        this.SetResourceReference(ContentProperty, resourceKey);   
    }

    public void DoAction ()
    {
        if (Action!=null)
        {
            Action();
        }
    }

    public delegate void ClickAction ();
    private ClickAction Action;

    public Object Content
    {
        get { return (Object)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Name.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty=DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(Object), typeof(MenuItem), new PropertyMetadata("leer?"));
}
```

And this is the XAML Style for the ListBox:

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ItemBrush" Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedItemBrush" Color="Orange" />
    <Style x:Key="RoundedItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border Name="ItemBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="8,0,0,0" Margin="0" Padding="5" Background="{StaticResource ItemBrush}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Content.Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Normal" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

ListBox used like this in XAML:

```
<ListBox
    x:Name="gui_listbox_menu"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource RoundedItem}"
    Background="Transparent"
    SelectionChanged="gui_listbox_menu_SelectionChanged"
    Margin="0,20,0,0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:Dlg_Main}}}"
/>
```

After startup the MenuItems have the correct translation, so the Reference works?!
but if i change the language during runtime only the MenuItems still showing the old language!

If i add an Button programmatically and set its ReferenceSource to the DynamicResource its content will change during runtime, too!

```
        Button btn_test=new Button();
        btn_test.Content="test";
        btn_test.Width=100;
        btn_test.Height=100;
        gui_tab_settings_grid.Children.Add(btn_test);
        btn_test.SetResourceReference(Button.ContentProperty, "DLG_MAIN_TITLE");
```

But my MenuItems do not change during runtime??!

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: Perhaps your `MenuItem`s *don't work* as you call it, because you are trying to call the `SetResourceReference` method from the constructor before your `Resource`s are loaded. Try calling that later and seeing what happens.

Comment: Resources are loaded before! The correct loaded translation will be displayed after start up !! but if i change the translation during runtime only the MenuItem's will not change and stay in "last language" ..

Comment: see [set-custom-markupextension-from-code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489789/set-custom-markupextension-from-code)

Comment: @pushpraj, the question author has already stated *I have read that MarkUpExtensions cannot be added programmatically*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whats the difference, but here is the "new" MenuItem class..

It derives now ListBoxItem ..

```
public class MenuItem : ListBoxItem
{
    public MenuItem (string resourceKey, ClickAction action)
    {
        Action=action;

        this.SetResourceReference(ContentProperty, resourceKey);   
    }

    public void DoAction ()
    {
        if (Action!=null)
        {
            Action();
        }
    }

    public delegate void ClickAction ();
    private ClickAction Action;
}
```