# Binding of ItemsSource property to enum type in code

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am writing a custom adorner for one of my controls. I want to add a context menu to this adorner and fill one of its items with the values of an enum. I know how to do such a binding in XAML:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="Color" ItemsSource={Binding Source={local:EnumBindingSource {x:Type local:MyColorEnum}, ReturnStrings=True}, Mode=OneTime}/>
</ContextMenu>
```

where EnumBindingSource is a custom MarkupExtension I wrote for that purpose:

```
public class EnumBindingSource : MarkupExtension
{
    private Type enumType;
    public Type EnumType
    {
        get => enumType;
        set
        {
            if (enumType != value)
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    Type type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(value) ?? value;
                    if (!type.IsEnum)
                        throw new ArgumentException("Type must be an enum type");
                }
                enumType = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool ReturnStrings { get; set; }

    public EnumBindingSource() { }

    public EnumBindingSource(Type enumType)
    {
        this.enumType = enumType;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        // code to turn enum values into strings, not relevant to the problem
    }
}
```

In this case, I can't create the binding in XAML because the adorner does not have any XAML code. I want to instead create the binding in C#, which I try to do like this:

```
internal class MyAdorner : Adorner, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    (...)
    
    public MyAdorner(UIElement adornedElement) : base(adornedElement)
    {
        (...)
        
        ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        MenuItem color = new MenuItem()
        {
            Header = "Color"
        };
        color.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding()
        {
            Source = new EnumBindingSource(typeof(MyColorEnum))
            {
                ReturnStrings = true
            },
            Mode = BindingMode.OneTime
        });
        contextMenu.Items.Add(color);
        this.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
    }
}
```

but this fails, it creates nothing. Unfortunately any sources I found online on creating bindings in code do not offer sufficient information for this particular case.

Any help is, as always, greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should reformulate your question to simplify it, the fact that it is an adorner or a context menu or that you have a really complicated `MarkupExtension` derived class as nothing to do with you issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set custom MarkupExtension from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489789/set-custom-markupextension-from-code)

Comment: @Orace wanted to be precise and complete so people won't have to wonder what I'm doing or ask for code X but I agree the ProvideValue method is not relevant. I was on the fence about adding it to the question. I edited it out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write this:

```xml
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={local:MyMarkup}}"
```

The xaml engine doesn't directly put the `MyMarkup` object in the source property.
It calls the `MarkupExtension.ProvideValue` method with an `IProvideValueTarget` as argument.
The returned object is the `Source`.

So the equivalent C# code is:

```csharp
var ebs = new EnumBindingSource(typeof(MyColorEnum)) { ReturnStrings = true };
color.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding()
{
    Source = ebs.ProvideValue(null), // provide a IServiceProvider is hard
    Mode = BindingMode.OneTime
});
```

By the way, you don't need a binding since the source will not change (`MarkupExtension` doesn't override `INotifyPropertyChanged`).
Then you can write:

```xml
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="Color" ItemsSource="{local:EnumBindingSource {x:Type local:MyColorEnum}, ReturnStrings=True}" />
</ContextMenu>
```

Working demo of a [MRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example) available [here](https://github.com/Orace/SO/tree/main/SO_72659645).

Comment: Thank you very much, this works. Didn't realize simply passing null for an IServiceProvider would work.